# Annotated Bibliography with achemso/ in ACS style

Tags: bibliographies, achemso

I am trying to make an annotated bibliography. The full citation should be followed by a short summary. The citation style should follow the ACS style, this is why I am using the `achemso` package. I am looking either for a way which automatically generates an annotated bibliography from the "annotate" field, or a way to include full references in text. I have seen the answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33008/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-create-annotated-bibliographies-e-g-in-a-li) question, however, `\bibentry` or `\fullcite` don't seem to work with achemso.

Is there a way to include full citations in the text with achemso? Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: @Guido: yes, but then it appends it to the citation, only separated by a comma. Doesn't really look nice, and I don't know enough so I could change this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer here is 'not without creating a modified `.bst`, as the `achemso` style is meant to reproduce the published ACS style. However, you could look at the `chem-acs` style for `biblatex`. As `biblatex` makes it much easier to modify output on-the-fly, it's more suitable to this kind of minor customisation (it might even work with the `annotate` field out of the box: untested).

Note: `chem-acs` is written by me, as is `achemso`, and the styles should be identical in output other than minor variations due to differences between `biblatex` and traditional BibTeX.