# How to cite papers within research paper without displaying the bibliography at the end

Tags: bibliographies

As the title suggests I would like to reference papers in my bib file but I dont want those references to appear at the end of my document. How could this be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried leaving `\printbibliography` out? I don't know, if this works, but give it a try. Btw. you should give us more information about what you want to do. What is the value of a citation without reference?

Comment: As its stands it is really hard to answer your question because it lacks basic information about what system you use to obtain a bibliography. Please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) indicating what "cite"/"bib" packages you use (e.g. `natbib`, `cite`, `biblatex` to name but a few), what style you use (maybe not that important here) etc.

Answer (score 3):

From your previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171557/27635) I assume you're using a normal BibTeX bibliography, so the solution is to use the package [`bibentry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibentry)

```
\usepackage{bibentry}
```

and use the command `\nobibliography` instead of `\bibliography`.

The package also provides a command `\bibentry` to print the whole bibliography entry without printing the bibliography.

MWE (borrowed from your previous question):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bibentry}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@inproceedings{marolt2002neural,
  title={Neural networks for note onset detection in piano music},
  author={Marolt, Matija and Kavcic, Alenka and Privosnik, Marko},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the International Computer Music Conference},
  year={2002}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{sample}

Here I want to cite \cite{marolt2002neural} but I don't want the bibliography to be printed.

This is the complete entry: 

\noindent\bibentry{marolt2002neural}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]