# How to customize bibtex numbering in a document?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I have a simple LaTeX document that has some BibTeX references:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
 
\section{First section}
 
This document is an example of \texttt{thebibliography} environment using 
in bibliography management. Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} 
book \cite{latexcompanion}, the Einstein journal paper \cite{einstein}, and the 
Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}. The \LaTeX\ related items are
\cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 
 
\medskip
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sample}
 
\end{document}
```

The output of this is as follows.

[image]

I would like to change the numbering of the reference in the text and in the References section with some set of specific numbers of my choice. How can I do this?

Let us say I would like to have something like this:

1 First section

This document is an example of thebibliography environment using in
bibliography management. Three items are cited: The LATEX Companion
book [11], the Einstein journal paper [22], and the Donald Knuth's website [33].
The LATEX related items are [11, 33].

References

[11] Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin. The LATEX
Companion. Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.

[22] Albert Einstein. Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Korper. (German) [On the
electrodynamics of moving bodies]. Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891{921,
1905.

[33] Donald Knuth. Knuth: Computers and typesetting.

Can I do this with LaTeX and BibTeX?

Comment: This seems a very strange thing to want to do. Do you want an arbitrarily assigned number to an arbitrary reference, or is there a system to this? In your example it looks like you want the citation number to be a multiple of 11.  Is this by design?

Comment: No. I have a set of numbers, say, 9, 3, and 14 and when I cite the first reference I would like it to appear as [9]. When I cite the second reference I would like to appear as [3]. Finally, when I cite the last reference, I would like it to appear as [14].

Comment: I need this because I have a document with normal BibTeX references like [1], [2], etc. and I am writing a letter that uses some of the references of the document. So, for example, I need to cite references [9], [3] and [14] in the letter. If I use normal BibTeX I would get [1], [2] and [3].

Comment: Since this is a one-off type use, I would do the citation numbers manually and use a normal list and the `bibentry` package to create the reference list.  The approach here is what I have in mind: [What is the most convenient way to create annotated bibliographies, e.g. in a literature review?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33008/2693)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can first prepare your bibliography in the usual way. Then you can set the numbers you prefer in the way shown below, by adding the code between `%%START` and `%%END`.

The `filecontents` environment is used just for the example, use your own database.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Knuth1984texbook,
    Author = {Knuth, D.E.},
    Title = {The \TeX book, volume A of Computers and typesetting},
    Publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    Year = {1984},
}
@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957},
}
@book{Chomsky1965,
    Address = {Cambridge Mass.},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {MIT Press},
    Title = {Aspects of the Theory of Syntax},
    Year = {1965},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch} % also loads expl3

%%START
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@bibitem}
  {\item}
  {\item[\@biblabel{\changekey{#1}}]}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@bibitem}
  {\the\value{\@listctr}}
  {\changekey{#1}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \changekey #1
 {
  \str_case:nVF {#1} \g_changekey_list_tl { ?? }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \setchangekey #1 #2
 {
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_changekey_list_tl { {#1}{#2} }
 }
\tl_new:N \g_changekey_list_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { nV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setchangekey{Knuth1984texbook}{9}
\setchangekey{Chomsky1957}{3}
\setchangekey{Chomsky1965}{7}
%%END

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

This document is an example of \texttt{thebibliography} environment using 
 bibliography management. Three items are cited: \emph{Syntactic Structures} 
book \cite{Chomsky1957}, \emph{Aspects} \cite{Chomsky1965}, and  
Donald Knuth's \TeX book \cite{Knuth1984texbook}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub>I used the same data as Alan Munn just for laziness.</sub>

Comment: Note that when using hyperref you should replace \item by \H@item in the first \xpatchcmd to make it compatible (and hyperref should be imported before the patch).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version of the solution I suggested to get you going. Given the limited use of this, it's probably not worth making the solution any more sophisticated.  The basic syntax of a reference is:

```
\mycite{<number>}{<bib-key>}
```

If you want to refer to an already used citation (introduced with `\mycite`) you can simply use `\ref{<bib=key}`.

You then introduce the actual bibliography items using the `\mybib` for each item.  These will appear with the number you used in the `\mycite` command, and will appear in the order in which you enter them in the `itemize` environment.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Knuth1984texbook,
    Author = {Knuth, D.E.},
    Title = {The TEXbook, volume A of Computers and typesetting},
    Year = {1984}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}

@book{Chomsky1965,
    Address = {Cambridge Mass.},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    Title = {Aspects of the Theory of Syntax},
    Year = {1965}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{bibright}{\hss\llap{[#1]}}
\newcounter{mynum}
\newcommand\mycite[2]{[#1]\setcounter{mynum}{0}\addtocounter{mynum}{#1-1}\refstepcounter{mynum}\label{#2}}
\newcommand\mybib[1]{\item[\ref{#1}]\bibentry{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

This document is an example of \texttt{thebibliography} environment using 
 bibliography management. Three items are cited: \emph{Syntactic Structures} 
book \mycite{6}{Chomsky1957}, \emph{Aspects} \mycite{4}{Chomsky1965}, and  
Donald Knuth's TeXBook \mycite{10}{Knuth1984texbook}. The Linguistics related items are
[\ref{Chomsky1965},\ref{Chomsky1957}].
\medskip
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\nobibliography{\jobname}
\begin{itemize}[labelwidth=!,labelsep=1em,align=bibright]
\mybib{Chomsky1957}
\mybib{Chomsky1965}
\mybib{Knuth1984texbook}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments, I think there is mauch easier way: There is the nice package `xcite`, this will let you import cites from your other document and you don't need to worry about the numbers (the following example assumes that the other document is called `document.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcite}
\externalcitedocument{document}

\begin{document}

\cite{knuth}


\end{document}
```