# How to Provide Explanations On BibTeX References?

Tags: bibtex

I want to provide further information on each reference, like what they could expect to find in that particular reference. Kind of like the below image[image]

However, I have been working with BibTeX so far. Is there a way to add these further explanations to the reference list which BibTeX produces? I mean at the end of each reference, could I write a couple of sentences? I found a similar thing by adding those explanatory phrases in the notes section of each BibTeX reference ,but I cannot force the notes to appear in the output.

Comment: Some options: 1. switch to a BibTeX style that shows the notes (most styles do), 2. use the `bibentry` package as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49048/how-to-cite-one-bibentry-in-full-length-in-the-body-text to add full citations in-text and repeat them in the Bibliography without explanations, 3. Use conventional citations in the text (Problem 2-6 is taken from `\cite{Kendall77}`) and show the bibliography at the end without explanations, 4. manually edit the `.bbl` file once you have added all references.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33008/2693