# Annotated Bibliography

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to create an annotated bibliography. Here's my `.tex` document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\title{Annotated Bibliography}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliography{annotatedbib}

\end{document}
```

And here is the associated `.bib` document:

```
@Misc{hacker,
    AUTHOR = `{Andrew Hacker'},
    TITLE = {Is Algebra Necessary?},
    HOWPUBLISHED = {New York Times},
    MONTH = {July 31},
    YEAR = {2012},
    ANNOTE = {This article was published in the New York Times.},
}
```

No matter into which format I compile my `.tex` document, the annotation will not show up! Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) There is no field `ANNOTE`. There is a field `note`. Here you can see which fields are defined: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36248/url-of-cited-web-site-in-bibliography/36255#36255

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use a bibliography style that does annotations; for instance `annotate.bst`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Misc{hacker,
    AUTHOR = {Andrew Hacker},
    TITLE = {Is Algebra Necessary?},
    HOWPUBLISHED = {New York Times},
    MONTH = {July 31},
    YEAR = {2012},
    ANNOTATE = {This article was published in the New York Times.},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\title{Annotated Bibliography}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{annotate}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Note that the field should be called `annotate`, not `annote`; here's the output. The `filecontents*` environment is just to keep the example selfcontained, you can continue to use an external file.

[image]

Another style that does annotations (with the `annote` field) is `chicago-annote` that requires `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}`.

Comment: Is there something like this similar to the plain bibliography style?

Comment: I don't know. I ran a search for files having `annot` and `.bst`, finding those two. Probably `biblatex` is better at it.

Comment: Here is a link to a page that describes the use of the plain-anote.bst file:
http://math.ucdenver.edu/~billups/courses/ma5779/annotated_bibliography.html Here is the link to plain-annote.bst:
http://math.ucdenver.edu/~billups/courses/ma5779/plain-annote.bst

Comment: In your example it is showing the title "References". But for annotated bibliography I want to omit the title. How to do it? I can't find where is the title coming from?

Comment: @user3436002: Please post follow-up questions as new questions not as answer posts (I converted your to a comment now). In this case your question was already asked: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132646/how-to-remove-the-references-title

Comment: How can this be done with biblatex and biber? Including `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=???]{biblatex}` in my preamble, there doesn't seem to be a good choice for `style` that prints the `annotation` field.

Comment: @MikePierce That's a completely different cup of tea.

Comment: Figured it out! :) Gotta use the `reading` style with another option, `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=reading,annotation=true]{biblatex}` to get the annotations to print, as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30511/52612). In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33008/52612), it also looks like the `\fullcite{}` command could be used to create an annotated bibliography in the body of the document, rather than in the references/bibliography itself.